# How can I check if a table cell is empty in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm a bit new to EXTJS and I would like to know how can I check if a table cell is empty in extjs. I know how to do it in Jquery but not in extJS

```
if ($(td).text() == "") {
                   //Do Something
         }
```

Comment: Which version of Ext JS are you using?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're talking about a grid or just a `td` element?

Comment: I'm just talking about a TD element.

Comment: I believe 3 I'm using version. Will the code be different for version 4?

Comment: Evan, I think its a grid but it outputs as a table thta's why I went with finding out if the TD selector was empty. Not sure if this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To verify if a variable is null, undefined or empty in ExtJS, you could use

```
Ext.isEmpty(Mixed value, [Boolean allowBlank]) : Boolean
```

Returns true if the passed value is null, undefined or an empty string (optional).

### Parameters:

- **value** : *Mixed*

  - The value to test
- **allowBlank** : *Boolean*

  - *(optional)* Pass true if an empty string is not considered empty
- **Returns** :

  - *Boolean*

**EDIT : Whooops, I've read array cell, sorry for the unappropriate response :c**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use getCell method. You need to pass record as row selector and column number.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getCell

Or you can use getNode method to obtain related TR HTMLElement and using down method find required column.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getNode
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-down